# WebAPI: ApiController with a URL string / URI parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to have a ApiController that has an action with a URI or URL parameter.

```
http://testserver/api/Controller?id=http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

I implemented actions like:

```
public bool Get(string id)
{
  ...
}
```

or

```
public bool Get(Uri id)
{
  ...
}
```

However: Whenever I call the URL as stated above, I get an 400 - Error - Bad Request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the problem you are describing. This should work. Here are the steps I have tried:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application using the Empty template
2. Add an Api controller:

   ```
   public class ValuesController : ApiController
   {
       public HttpResponseMessage Get(Uri id)
       {
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, id);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run the application and navigate to `/api/values/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stackoverflow.com`
4. The id parameter is correctly bound to the Get action argument

So could you provide the steps allowing us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Ah! That's a Problem of the "Cassini" Visual Studio Webserver. As soon as I ran it in IIS Express it worked ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that I used "Cassini", the VS integrated webserver.
As soon as I ran it in IIS Express, it worked.